# summation over partial multinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

So the standard multinomial theorem states that
$$
\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_m} \binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_m}\cdot [i_1+\cdots +i_m=n]=m^n
$$
where the summation is over non-negative numbers and $[\cdot]$  is the indicator function that equals $1$ if and only if $\cdot$ is satisfied and $0$ otherwise. Now, do we know anything about say (for even $m$ and $n$ being a power of $2$),
$$
\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_m} \binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_m}\cdot [i_1+\cdots +i_{m/2+1}\geq n/2]\cdot [i_1+\cdots +i_m=n]?
$$
or
$$
\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_m} \binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_m}\cdot [i_1+\cdots +i_{m/2+2}\geq 3n/4]\cdot [i_1+\cdots +i_m=n]?
$$
or in general
$$
\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_m} \binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_m}\cdot [i_1+\cdots +i_{m/2+k}\geq (2^k-1)n/2^k]\cdot [i_1+\cdots +i_m=n]?
$$
for arbitrary $k\in \{1,\ldots,m/2\}$? Eventually for large enough $k$ this just converges to the standard multonimial theorem statement.

In general, I'm looking to understand or upper bound the following quantity
$$
\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_m} \binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_m}\cdot \prod_{k=1}^{m/2}[i_1+\cdots +i_{m/2+k}\geq (2^k-1)n/2^k]
$$
Any pointers/help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $\displaystyle m\ \mbox{and}\ n\ even\ \mbox{or}\ odd$ ?.

Comment: Right. Thanks! i added in this assumption. In fact I'm fine making assumptions of the form they are even, powers of $2$ and so on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{m\ \mbox{and}\ n}$ are *even* numbers. Then, lets set
$m \equiv 2M$ and $n = 2N$ where $\ds{M, N, \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 0}}$.

Lets study one of the above expressions. Namely, the first *non standard* one:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k_{1},\ldots,k_{2m}}{2N \choose k_{1},\ldots,k_{2M}}
\bracks{k_{1} + \cdots + k_{M + 1} \geq N}}
\\[5mm] = &
\sum_{s = N}^{\infty}\sum_{k_{1},\ldots,k_{2M}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\pars{2N}! \over k_{1}!,\ldots,k_{2M}!}
\bracks{k_{1} + \cdots + k_{M + 1} = s}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{2N}!\sum_{s = N}^{\infty}\sum_{k_{1},\ldots,k_{2M}\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k_{1}!,\ldots,k_{2M}!}
\bracks{z^{\large s}}z^{k_{1} + \cdots + k_{M + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{2N}!\sum_{s = N}^{\infty}\bracks{z^{\large s}}
\pars{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{z^{k} \over k!}}^{M + 1}
\pars{\sum_{q = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over q!}}^{M - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{2N}!\expo{M - 1}\sum_{s = N}^{\infty}\bracks{z^{\large s}}
\expo{\pars{M + 1}z}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\pars{2N}!\,\expo{M - 1}
\sum_{s = N}^{\infty}{\pars{M + 1}^{s} \over s!}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Nice! I just realized I made one mistake in what I wrote (extremely sorry about it). Not only do i want the indicator $[k_1+...+k_{M+1}\geq N]$ but I also want $[k_1+...+k_{2M}=2N]$. Let me see if the calculations you wrote can also be tweaked to add this extra constraint!

Comment: @Annonymous I hope so !!!. Thanks.